# postgres update table not working after a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, transactions

so wrote a code to update a postgres table and display on a browser. Below is the part of the code. This code was working fine but after a couple of week the code below doesnt seem to work.The postgres table does not update after executing this code. I have even checked my codes timeline and there no no changes to the code.Is there something that im missing in the code.

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const sessions = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine','ejs');
const pool = new Pool({
user : 'postgres',
host : 'localhost',
database : 'postgres',
password : 'wasay123',
port : 5432,
})


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
const oneDay = 1000 * 1200 ;
app.use(sessions({
secret: "SecretKey",
saveUninitialized:true,
cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
resave: false 
}));

const myusername = 'mark'
const mypassword = 'was'

var session;

app.get('/web',(req,res) => {
session=req.session;
if(session.userid){
    res.render('log');
}else
res.render('web');

});


app.post('/',(req,res) => {
if(req.body.username == myusername && req.body.password == 
mypassword){
    session=req.session;
    session.userid=req.body.username;
    console.log(req.session);
    res.render('log');
}
else{
    res.send('wrong credentials');
}
})

app.get('/logout',(req,res) => {
 req.session.destroy();
res.redirect('/web');
});

app.get('/',  function (req, res) {
res.render('web');
});

app.get('/balance',(req,res)=>{ 

pool.query("SELECT * FROM accounts",function(err,result){
    session=req.session;
    if(session.userid){
        res.render('balance',{data:result.rows});
    }else{
    res.render('rest'); }
});

});
app.get('/transactions',  function (req, res) {

session=req.session;
if(session.userid){
    res.render('transactions');
}else{
    res.render('rest'); }

 });

 app.get('/history', function (req, res) {
session=req.session;
if(session.userid){
    res.render('history');
}else{
    res.render('rest'); }
});

app.post("/", async (req,res) => {
 pool.query(`UPDATE accounts SET "balance" = "balance" - 
${req.body.amountt} WHERE "name" = ${req.body.from} `);
pool.query(`UPDATE accounts SET "balance" = "balance" + 
${req.body.amountt} WHERE "name" = ${req.body.to} `);
pool.query(`INSERT INTO history(FromPerson,ToPerson,amount) 
values(${req.body.from},${req.body.to},${req.body.amountt})`);

res.redirect('/transactions');
console.log(req.body);   
 }); 

app.listen(8084, () => console.log("Web server is listening.. 
on port 8084"))

sid()
async function sid() {
try {
    await pool.connect(); 
    console.log('connected');
}
catch(e) {
    console.error(`Failed to connect ${e}`);
 }
}
```

Comment: Does it return any error in the console?
Are you sure your connection to the database is preserved?

Comment: No,there is not error in the console. Can you elaborate what do you mean by connection is preserved?

Comment: Can your node server still connect to the database?

Comment: yes it is connected. I see no errors.

Comment: i seem not be able to perform any queries

Comment: i have updated my question to add the whole program